# Django Rest Framework: How to pass value using url and perform calculation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django and created simple api which displays message using GET method

views.py:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def message(request):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    return Response({"Print": "GET request from browser works"}, status=status. HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='Home'),
    path('message',views.message,name='message'),
]
```

Output:
[image]

Now I want to take 2 inputs from user through url and perform addition on that inputs and return its result using GET and POST methods.

Example: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/?a=2&b=3` (something like this) and it should return addition results.

Most of tutorials online are on fetching data from database but I want to create api which takes input from user and return its output.

Can anyone show me how to achieve above task?

Comment: you can use `request.query_params` in your function to access `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`query_params`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) for this:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def message(request):
  a = request.query_params.get('a')
  b = request.query_params.get('b')
       
  return Response({"Print": "a = {}, b={}".format(a,b), status=status. HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you please guide me how to provide values of a and b through URL, when I tried `http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/?a=2&b=3` I am getting error as **Page not fount** and how to achieve this using POST also

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/?a=2&b=3` should work just fine. Please verify your urls.py if it is pointing correctly to the view

Comment: I've edited the question and pasted my urls.py, can you please review it and let me know if any modification needed

Comment: Are you making `POST` requests?

Comment: okay, can you try with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/message?a=2&b=3 ` OR change the url to `path('message/',views.message,name='message'),`?

Comment: Thanks!!!, It's working now. Last question, if I want to achieve same task with POST, what should I change in your Code??

Comment: you can just add `POST` in `@api_view` decorator